# select column value from row by column index - laravel php

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to select column value from a row by column index. I am trying to fetch data from a mysql database by using laravel php framework. I am able to select column value by its name but I didn't find a way to select by column index.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        public function sample_name()
        {
            $page_title = 'Page1';
            $page_description = 'Some description for the page';
            
            $action = __FUNCTION__;
    
            $table = DB::select("my select query");
    
            foreach ($table as $value) {

               // I want to select first column value from this row
               $first_column_value = .....

            }
    
            return view('home.page', compact('page_title', 'page_description','action'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried array_values($array) which returns all the values by index.

Comment: hmmm, i don't know if I understood you well, but why don't you simply use `$value['column name']` ?!

Comment: - Moussab Kbeisy , because my query is little bit complicated.in the result column names may be change but order never change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you can't access with index because `$value` is associative array, to access by index you can use `array_value($array)` which return the index array

```
foreach($table as $value){
  $value=array_values((array)$value);
  $first_column_value =$value[0];
  $second_column_value =$value[1];
}
```

Comment: TypeError
array_values(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, stdClass given

Comment: $value = array_values((array)$value); this worked !

Comment: yeah I have also updated the answer